# How do I find the date/time set on an EMC Symmetrix?

Tags: emc

I'd like to find out what date and time (and possibly time zone) a Symmetrix (DMX-4 and VMAX) is set to.  I've checked Powerlink as well as the man pages for symcli, but nothing pops out.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a timezone displayed using:

`symcfg -sid XXXX -v list`

I do not know if the timezone displayed is for the Symm or for the host the CLI is running on, however.

Comment: The time zone displayed is for the host the CLI is running on.  I just tested this against an array using two different hosts in different time zones, and I got the time zones for the hosts.